# Foreach loop logically correct, but outcome is wrong

Tags: php, xml, laravel

```
<?php
            $xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            $json = json_encode($xml);
            $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
?>
  <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>TITLE</th>
                        <th>ARTIST</th>
                        <th>COUNTRY</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach ($array as $books)
                        @foreach ( $books as $ddd)
                            @foreach (  $ddd as $key => $value)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{  $value }}</td>
                            <td>{{  $value }}</td>
                            <td>{{  $value }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </table>
```

How my foreach loop outcome can be like this one?
I tried various foreach loops, combinations, either got string to array conversion errors or undefined indexes, when i tried do for each loop twice i got an array is given string is needed error.
Mainly here i converted xml to array using json encode and decode technique and did for each loop to fill the table with data

```
   <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>TITLE</th>
                    <th>ARTIST</th>
                    <th>COUNTRY</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach ($xml->children() as $books)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{  $books->TITLE }}</td>
                                <td>{{  $books->ARTIST }}</td>
                                <td>{{  $books->COUNTRY }}</td>


                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$array` variable contains a single entry, called `CD`, which contains an array of books. So, you need to use a nested `foreach()`, or assign a new variable `$books` to `$array["CD"]`, then loop over that:

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

    $books = $array["CD"];
?>

...

@foreach($books AS $book)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $book["TITLE"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book["ARTIST"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book["COUNTRY"] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach

// OR

@foreach($array AS $booksAlt)
@foreach($booksAlt AS $bookAlt)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $bookAlt["TITLE"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bookAlt["ARTIST"] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bookAlt["COUNTRY"] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted this to pure PHP but you should be able to change it back to Blade syntax easily enough.

I think you just went 1-level too deep. If you loop over `$array` and then over `$track`, you should have access to all the info you need.

Using the *sane variable names* will help you keep track of the hierarchy. You're retrieving a CD and its associated tracks so I named the variables accordingly.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
?>

<pre>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>TITLE</th>
        <th>ARTIST</th>
        <th>COUNTRY</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($array as $cd): ?>
        <?php foreach ($cd as $track): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $track['TITLE']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $track['ARTIST']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $track['COUNTRY']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</pre>
```